# Find any lines exceeding a certain length

Tags: text-processing

Is it possible to find any lines in a file that exceed 79 characters?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

In order of decreasing speed (on a GNU system in a UTF-8 locale and on ASCII input) according to my tests:

```
grep '.\{80\}' file

perl -nle 'print if length$_>79' file

awk 'length>79' file

sed -n '/.\{80\}/p' file
```

Except for the `perl`¹ one (or for `awk`/`grep`/`sed` implementations (like `mawk` or busybox) that don't support multi-byte characters), that counts the length in terms of number of *characters* (according to the `LC_CTYPE` setting of the locale) instead of *bytes*.

If there are bytes in the input that don't form part of valid characters (which happens sometimes when the locale's character set is UTF-8 and the input is in a different encoding), then depending on the solution and tool implementation, those bytes will either count as 1 character, or 0 or not match `.`.

For instance, a line that consists of 30 `a`s a 0x80 byte, 30 `b`s, a 0x81 byte and 30 UTF-8 `é`s (encoded as 0xc3 0xa9), in a UTF-8 locale would not match `.\{80\}` with GNU `grep`/`sed` (as that standalone 0x80 byte doesn't match `.`), would have a length of 30+1+30+1+2*30=122 with `perl` or `mawk`, 3*30=90 with `gawk`.

If you want to count in terms of bytes, fix the locale to `C` with `LC_ALL=C grep/awk/sed...`.

That would have all 4 solutions consider that line above contains 122 characters. Except in `perl` and GNU tools, you'd still have potential issues for lines that contain NUL characters (0x0 byte).

---

<sup>¹ the `perl` behaviour can be affected by the `PERL_UNICODE` environment variable though</sup>

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: I think manatwork means typing efficiency. `awk` can come closer if you drop `($0)`, which is implicit anyway ;).

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification. I don't particularly care about speed though.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking to performance. But GNU `grep` had a surprise for me: it beat `awk`. So I had to edit it.

Comment: @manatwork how often did you run each test, and how did you measure performance?

Comment: @Thor, I put an output with some details on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/CLtP2iSH

Comment: @manatwork, interesting, I ran similar tests with mostly similar [results](http://pastebin.com/y3tj7fkN), although `sed` seems to be doing something wrong.

Comment: BTW, if you anchor the regexp to the beginning of the line with `^`, it's slightly faster: e.g. `grep '^.\{80\}' file`.

Comment: The perl solution does not account for variable size encoding such as UTF-8, unlike all the other solutions.

Comment: mawk runs the length function quite a bit faster than the gnu awk, might try that.

Comment: Sufficiently large values of N fail with grep but succeed with awk. (e.g. `grep '^.\{1000\}' file` returns `grep: invalid repetition count(s)`, while `awk 'length>1000' file` succeeds.)

Comment: return only the line numbers: `grep -n '.\{80\}' file | cut -f1 -d:`

Answer (score 1):

Shell approach:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ];
do 
    [ "${#line}" -gt 79 ] && printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < input.txt
```

Python approach:

```
python -c 'import sys;f=open(sys.argv[1]);print "\n".join([ l.strip() for l in f if len(l) >79 ]);f.close()' input.txt
```

Or as a short script for readability:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line) > 79:
            print line.strip()
```

If we wanted to exclude newline character `\n` from calculations, we can make `if len(line) > 79` be `if len(line.strip()) > 79`

Side note: this is Python 2.7 syntax. Use `print()` for Python 3