# How to find lines containing more than 100 characters and contains "if"?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, regular-expression

So, probably I should use `grep` for this. As long as I need recursive search I should use `grep -r`. But then I don't know what should I do next ;)

How can I do that?

Comment: `find . -type f -exec awk 'length > 100 && /if/' {} +`

Comment: I wince at the thought of ever having to search through a codebase for Lines with an if statement more then 100 characters to refactor :-Z

Comment: @Falco The statement itself could be simple, just indented out quite a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use two greps connected by a pipe:

```
grep -r '.\{100\}' /path | grep 'if'
```

To exclude files with `if` in their paths or names, use `':.*if'` instead of `'if'` (could still break if your filenames or paths contain colons).

Comment: Note that it could report all the 100 character lines in files that have `if` in their path

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: True. You can use `':.*if'` to prevent that (unless your filenames contain colons).

Answer (score 14):

With `grep`s that support the `-r` (recursive) and `-P` (PCRE) options (or `pcregrep` with `-r`):

```
grep -rP '^(?=.{101}).*?if' .
```

Or POSIXly:

```
find . -type f -exec awk 'length > 100 && /if/ {
   print FILENAME ": " $0}' {} +
```

(note that the behaviour will vary between implementations for non-text files (files containing non-characters, zero byte values, too long lines or data after the last newline). Also note that some `grep` implementations will search in non-regular files or will follow symbolic links).

Comment: I'm only aware of one `grep` that does, and even that one requires its support built-in to the lib c to work as I understand it. Are there more?

Comment: @mikeserv, not sure what you mean with _lib c_. PCRE regexp support is generally provided by libpcre. An exception is the `grep` from ast-open that has its own implementation of perl-like regexps. grep implementations that support `grep -rP` do include GNU, FreeBSD/OS/X (a rewrite of GNU grep now diverging) and ast-open's

Answer (score 12):

Use awk to count size of $0 and presence of substring if?
`awk '( length($0) > 100 && index($0,"if") ){print}' file`

If "if" should be a word (as opposed to a simple substring), you could use 

`awk '( length($0) > 100 && match($0,/\<if\>/) ){print}' file`

Comment: The idiomatic way to write it in `awk` would be more like  `awk 'length > 100 && /if/' file`. Note that for `/\<if\>/`, you need GNU `awk`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yeah, I saw your syntax and learned the right way, but since you already posted an answer I didn't see the point in modifying mine. I did upvote your answer, though.

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from [Find any lines exceeding a certain length](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/find-any-lines-exceeding-a-certain-length) any of the following will work to find lines longer than 100 chars

```
grep '.\{100\}' file

perl -nle 'print if length$_>99' file

awk 'length($0)>99' file

sed -n '/.\{100\}/p' file
```

chose your preferred method and pipe it through `grep if`

Comment: The sed version can do both checks at once; example using GNU extensions: `sed -n '/.\{100\}/{/if/p}' file`.  Similarly the perl one: `perl -nle 'print if length$_>99 && /if/'`

Answer (score 3):

with a single `grep`:

```
grep -vxE '.{0,99}|([^i]|i[^f])*i*' <in >out
```

that will only select lines which cannot be described from head to tail with either statement. and so any line which can be described as consisting of between 0 and 99 characters will not be selected, and similarly any line which matches more than 99 characters and yet still does not contain at least a single *if* will also fail to be selected.

```sh
printf '^%-100b$\n' 'if\nif' 'hey if' i if |
grep -nvxE '.{0,99}|([^i]|i[^f])*i*'
```

---

```
3:^hey if                                                                                              $
5:^if                                                                                                  $
```

you might do better just to use two `grep`s, though.