# idn: debug minimum and maximum limit list

Tags: shell-script, domain

I am processing a big list of domains to convert to IDN with the following command:

```
cat list | idn > clean
```

list format example:

```
президент.рф
mañana.com
bücher.com
café.fr
cliché.com
hualañe.cl
köln-düsseldorfer-rhein-main.de
mūsųlaikas.lt
sendesık.com
sushicorner-würzburg.de
domain.com
# almost 1 M lines
```

But I get the following message

```
idn: idna_to_ascii_4z (big list): Output would be too big or too small
```

Then I must make sure that my list does not exceed the allowed limit (too big or too small)

I found this:

> [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) the length of a FQDN is limited to 255 characters, and each label (node delimited by a dot in the hostname) is limited to 63 characters

and

> 1-character limit botton (example: t.co)

**Question:** 
How do I remove from my list, domains with hostnames greater than 63 characters and less than 1, by command line? (bash to run idn without error)

**Actions:**
I have tried the following (although I wish it was all in one command) ([partial source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42899/266428)):

```
sed -n '/.\{63\}/p' list > out
grep -vi -f <(sed 's:^\(.*\)$:\\\1\$:' out) list | sort -u > out2
```

But when I run the idn command, the same message idn comes up

```
cat out2 | idn
idn: idna_to_ascii_4z (big list): Output would be too big or too small
```

I appreciate any help

PD: Maybe the problem is related to IDN and the size of the list (which is very large). **I do not know**. I have no information if IDN has any limitations on the number of lines | domains | hostnames to process. The help file does not provide much information on this point

**Update:**
The problem was solved, but the correct answer was eliminated by the author @cas, apparently due to a spam incident. Vote for closing

Comment: Check for double dots, e.g. `hello..com`.  You may do that with `grep -F '..' list`.

Comment: @Kusalananda the list is already clean of ".." (..com, etc). I use a TLDs validation system before processing it. I also use a system to remove overlapping domains (subdomain.domain.com and domain.com = only domain.com)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because U&L shouldn't be helping scammers.  or spammers.

Comment: cas' comment is in response to a pastebin link provided by ajcg showing various domain names. @ajcg, I'd encourage you to provide *representative* input data for your question.

Comment: @cas sorry about this spam incident. The problem is already solved thanks to you.

Comment: ajcg, it sounds like cas is concerned about the contents of the pastebin link, which is why they deleted their answer.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thank you for your concern. If 'cas' had told me, I delete the link. 'cas' must publish his answer again to select it as correct. Since he gave me a lot of additional information that helped me solve other additional problems I had on my list, not described in the question. That is why I consider that this selection deserves.

Comment: ... which is why I [encouraged you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537666/idn-debug-minimum-and-maximum-limit-list?noredirect=1#comment997552_537666) to post representative data so that Answerers could test their solution against it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `idn` has any switches to skip unacceptable strings instead of exiting with an error, so the only option left is to restart it after an *expected* error:

```
idn_skip(){
    while ! error=$(idn 2>&1 >&3); do
        case $error in *'Punycode failed'*|*'Output would be too large'*) ;; # restart
        *) break;;
        esac
    done 3>&1
}

idn_skip < domain_list
```

This is ugly and stupid, and will not work when reading the domain list from a non-seekable file (which could be fixed bash-style by running it as `stdbuf -i1 idn`, but that will only make it even more ridiculous).

Instead of trying to overcome `idn`'s limitations, my advice would be to use the `Net::LibIDN` perl package (`apt-get install libnet-libidn-perl` on debian) and write the whole thing in perl.

Comment: thank for your response